# What operations should change the modification-date of a directory?

Tags: directory, operating-system, filesystems

I am programming a tool that can backup or merge directories.

The modification-date of files is somewhat straightforward but what about the modification-date of a directory?

What operations are considered modification of a directory? (I would then call the OS's API to do that.)

How does the intended semantic differ based on operating systems and file systems?
Is it consistently updated by common 3rd party programs?

Do common 3rd party programs depend on a certain semantic of a directory's modification date? (Example: do incremental backup programs recurse into directories that claim the same modification date?)

Addition:

Here is another example (though I would prefer a broader scope):
When I am copying a directory from one drive to another: what actually happens is, that the outermost directory is created first and then recursively down to individual files being added. The last entry of any directory being added will by default change that directory's modification date. The result is that every directory will have a brand new modification date that has little informational value (and be different from that of the source-directories). One question is whether we want that to be the case or whether we want to then change that directory's modification date to be the same as that of the directory on the source-drive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't specify an operating system or a filesystem, and those have different operations, so for illustrative purposes, we'll take [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/contents.html), and by "modification time" we'll assume the discussion is about mtime (as opposed to ctime).

POSIX originates in Unix, where, like @itisravi said, a directory is just another type of file.

That means 2 things:

- Every system call that changes a file's mtime and can be called on a directory, can change the directory's mtime.
- Every system call which modifies the contents of the directory's inode data, namely the list of file names or the inode number associated with a file name in the list, will change the directory's mtime.

In the first category we have [`utime(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/utime.html#tag_16_639) and it's variants such as [`futimens(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/futimens.html#tag_16_181).

In the second category we have [`creat(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/creat.html#tag_16_79), [`open(2)` with `O_CREAT`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html#tag_16_357), [`mkdir(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkdir.html#tag_16_325), [`mkfifo(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mkfifo.html#tag_16_327), [`mknod(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/mknod.html#tag_16_328), [`bind(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/bind.html#tag_16_33) to a unix domain socket, [`rename(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rename.html#tag_16_487), [`link(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/link.html#tag_16_293), [`symlink(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/symlink.html#tag_16_594), [`unlink(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/unlink.html#tag_16_635), [`rmdir(2)`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rmdir.html#tag_16_491) and their variants.

All these links to the spec have the relevant section saying when they must update mtime.

What they *don't* have, is any specification about when mtime should *not* change. That means that the filesystem is essentially allowed to change mtime at any time to whatever it wants. Why do such a thing? here are a few examples:

- Background tasks e.g. to remove old files.
- Administrator restores filesystem to older snapshot.
- Implementation issues where optimizing or correcting errors in the background can't be done efficiently without updating mtime.
- [NFS silly rename](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#faq_d2) (but note that NFS is not POSIX-compliant).

However, in the context of the tool you're writing (a clone of [`rsync(1)`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync)?), there are other considerations:

- Metadata matters. If someone chowned a file inside a directory, it won't change the directory's modification time, but you still need to descend into the directory and do something there.
- Some tools, e.g. `cp -a` or [Caja](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/caja), will by default copy the metadata when they copy data. The metadata of the source data is indeed much more useful than the metadata of the newly created data.
- When you merge directories, you need to decide on a consistent definition of what the mtime will be set to. Probably "the latest of the two directories" is the most generally applicable definition.
- Besides backup tools like rsync, which sound similar to what you're doing, there's another family of tools interested in detecting changes - build tools. Tools like [`make(1)`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)) also [consider modification times](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Behavior), but that's "the old way", newer build tools hash the data they copy, and [detect changes based on hashes](https://scons.org/doc/0.98.2/HTML/scons-user/c779.html) - you might want to consider this option instead.

Answer (score 0):

It is apparent when you realize directories are files too, so anything that changes the contents of a directory will update its modification time. Since the contents of a dir are file names, essentially any entry operation (create, mkdir, rmdir, unlink etc.) inside a directory will update its mtime. You can also manually set the atime and mtime with the `utime(2)` syscall.

All of this is true on filesystems on Linux and various Unix operating system variants.